# Normals rotates wrong way when object is rotated

Tags: matrix, 3d, webgl, quaternions, gl-matrix

I am rendering a simple torus in WebGL. Rotating the vertices works fine but I have a problem with the normals. When rotated around a single axis, they keep the correct direction but when the rotation around a second axis increases, the normals start rotating the wrong way up until one of the rotations are 180°, then the normals are rotating in the complete opposite of what they should.
I assume the problem lies with the quaternion used for rotation, but I have not been able to determine what is wrong.

Here is a (slightly modified, but it still shows the problem) jsfiddle of my project: https://jsfiddle.net/dt509x8h/1/
*In the html-part of the fiddle there is a div containing all the data from the obj-file I am reading to generate the torus (although a lower resolution one).*

vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec3 aNormalDirection;

uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

varying vec3 nrm;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aVertexPosition;
    nrm = aNormalDirection * uNMatrix;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
varying vec3 nrm;

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(nrm, 1.0);
}
```

Updating the matrices (run when there has been input):

```
mat4.perspective(pMatrix, Math.PI*0.25, width/height, clipNear, clipFar); //This is actually not run on input, it is just here to show the creation of the perspective matrix
mat4.fromRotationTranslation(mvMatrix, rotation, position);
mat3.normalFromMat4(nMatrix, mvMatrix);

mat4.multiply(mvpMatrix, pMatrix, mvMatrix);

var uMVPMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
var uNMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uNMatrix");
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uMVPMatrix, false, mvpMatrix);
gl.uniformMatrix3fv(uNMatrix, false, nMatrix);
```

Creating the rotation quaternion (called when mouse has moved):

```
var d = vec3.fromValues(lastmousex-mousex, mousey-lastmousey, 0.0);
var l = vec3.length(d);
vec3.normalize(d,d);
var axis = vec3.cross(vec3.create(), d, [0,0,1]);
vec3.normalize(axis, axis);

var q = quat.setAxisAngle(quat.create(), a, l*scale);
quat.multiply(rotation, q, rotation);
```

Rotating the torus only around the Y-axis, the normals point in the right directions:
[image: Rotating the torus only around the Y-axis]
Rotating the torus around two axes. The normals are pointing all over the place:
[image: Rotating around two axes]

*I am using [glMatrix](http://glmatrix.net/) v2.3.2 for all matrix and quaternion operations.*

*Update:*
It seems that rotating only around the Z axis (by setting the input axis for `quat.setAxisAngle` explicitly to `[0,0,1]`, or by using `quat.rotateZ`) also causes the normals to rotate in the opposite direction.
Zeroing the z-component of the `axis` does not help.

*Update2:*
Rotating by `quat.rotateX(q, q, l*scale); quat.rotateY(q, q, l*scale); quat.multiply(rotation, q, rotation);` Seems correct, but as soon as rotation around Z is introduced the z normals starts to move around.
Using the difference in x or y mouse-values instead of `l` causes all normals to move, and so does using largely different `scale`-values for x and y.

*Update3:* changing the order of multiplication in the shader to  `uNMatrix * aNormalDirection` causes the normals to always rotate the wrong way.

Comment: Isnt it suppose to be `uNMatrix *  aNormalDirection;` in your fragment shader?

Comment: @WacławJasper I thought so as well, but after reading a bit, it seems that some put the normal-matrix on the left and [some on the right](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/version1.1/glspec1.1/node26.html), depending on how it has been created. Anyways, changing the order causes every rotation to be inverted for the normals.

Comment: That probably means one of the signs is flipped somewhere. Perhaps your `normalDirection` is pointing at the wrong way? Or perhaps pass a modelView matrix to the vertex shader and calculate the normal matrix as `transpose(inverse(modelView))` to see if that works? Or post a complete runnable example and I can take a look at it.

Comment: I did try flipping the normals as well as calculating the normal matrix from the model-view. I'll put up some runnable code in the morning.

Comment: @WacławJasper There is now a link to JSfiddle

Comment: Hold the phone! I have found the problem! When loading the obj-data, I reused some old code that apparently inverted the z-positions of the vertices for some reason. Removing this inversion seems to have fixed the problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case, the problem was with how I loaded the data from an .obj-file. *I had inverted the z-position of all vertices, but the normals were generated from the non-inverted vertices.*
Using non-inverted z-positions and flipping the normal-matrix multiplication fixed the issues.